# On what grounds can Trump's decision to end DACA be challenged?

Tags: united-states, immigration

[This question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/27357/2130) asks why Trump would be blocked from ending DACA, and the answer was that he wasn't - it was just suspended until all ongoing lawsuits against Trump's action were resolved, presumably to preserve the *status quo* and avoid any unreversible actions. However, it doesn't address why there are lawsuits against ending DACA in the first place.

On what grounds is the administration being sued to prevent DACA from being ended?  What justification do people provide to prevent an executive order from undoing an executive order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, from [the lawsuit](https://oag.ca.gov/system/files/attachments/press_releases/DACA%20Lawsuit.pdf), these are some of the argued grounds (formatting added, along with expanding a few acronyms):

> The Trump Administration's elimination of [DACA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_Action_for_Childhood_Arrivals) was unlawful on a number of grounds.
>
> - First, the DACA Rescission Memorandum violates the due process guarantee of the [Fifth Amendment to the United States Constitution](https://www.constituteproject.org/constitution/United_States_of_America_1992#147) by substantially altering Department of Homeland Security's (DHS) prior assurances regarding the use of information contained in DACA applications; Defendants should be equitably estopped from acting contrary to these assurances.
> - Second, Office of Homeland Security (OHS) promulgated this rule without providing notice or the opportunity to comment as required by the [Administrative Procedure Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_Procedure_Act_(United_States)) ("APA"), thereby depriving Plaintiff States of the opportunity to present important evidence to OHS about the overwhelming success of the DACA program in Plaintiff States as part of the rulemaking process.
> - Third, OHS violated the substantive requirements of the APA by proffering a legally insufficient justification for rescinding DACA, obscuring the true policy rationale for this substantial change, and otherwise violating independent constitutional and statutory provisions.
> - Fourth, federal law does not permit this substantive change in OHS policy to be made without an analysis of the negative impact of rescinding DACA on small businesses, non-profits, and local government entities, including those in Plaintiff States.
> - Finally, Defendants have discriminated against this class of young immigrants in violation of the equal protection guarantee of the Fifth Amendment by depriving them of their interests in pursuing a livelihood and furthering their education. These interests are substantial, and Defendants deprived DACA grantees of them without a sufficient justification.

Comment: So the claim here is not so much that Trump *can't* direct the OHS to do this, as that the way it was done was too rushed, not sufficiently justified, and may violate grantees' right to due process?

Comment: That's at least some of it.  The lawsuit has hundreds of paragraphs; this is just the one that seemed the most apt.

Comment: If this lawsuit is won, it can then be argued that a President, any President, including Trump, can make law unilaterally without congress.

Comment: @FrankCedeno I'm not sure how you get that from this situation.  Obama used a function of the executive branch to delay enforcing laws.  Trump used a function of the executive branch to no longer delay enforcing the laws.  No laws were created, no laws were undone.  It's kind of an unavoidable effect of living unlawfully in the country that one's continued presence is at the mercy of enforcement of the laws being violated, or those laws being changed (and it being decided that past violations are not grandfathered in as still extant violations).

Comment: @JackOfAllTrades234, the devil is in the details: The law that was made was: "an undocumented immigrant will be exempt from the law if he registers for 2 years".  The law would be enforced otherwise.  It was not a delay of existing law if it was still selectively enforced. Thus adding to the law which should be the jurisdiction of congress. I agree with you, but the lawsuit does not. The arguments are moot if it is simply delaying enforcement since there is not law that requires the acceptance of new registrations, nor the acceptance of any existing registrations.

Comment: @FrankCedeno Was that a new made law or was it an executive order? My understanding is that it was an executive order. If this lawsuit fails then it means that one party is allowed make laws by executive order but the other party isn't allowed to repeal them by executive order.

Comment: @Readin First of all, if the lawsuit *fails* that means the repeal is upheld.  Secondly, that's not necessarily true even if the lawsuit doesn't go the way you like.  Perhaps Obama jumped through the required APA procedural hoops and Trump didn't.  Perhaps nobody challenged the first order in court.  Etc.

Comment: @FrankCedeno Sorry, it looks like I did get "fails" and "succeeds" reversed.

Comment: @Readin, that is an interesting take. However, you can also parse it to mean that the law could be made, but not rescinded, which is even scarier. A dictatorship?

Comment: @FrankCedeno Obama didn't make a new law, he made a new qualification on an existing law. If this lawsuit succeeds, it might (depending on the grounds on which it succeeds) establish that executive orders can rescind laws, but it would not establish that executive orders can make laws.

Comment: @Acccumulation, a new qualification that did not exist on an existing law IS a new law. And by the way, what existing law allows undocumented aliens to remain, if they are undocumented? Undocumented includes not requesting asylum. The Constitution is very clear on the role of the President so that Executive orders are for Enforcing existing law, The Judiciary has the job of interpreting laws, not the President. This argument is for academic purposes only, in reality, I know that no matter what happens, it is bad news.

Comment: @FrankCedeno A qualification is less law, not more. It's odd to say that the  power to decrease government action makes for dictatorship. The president is head of the executive branch, and arguably that includes the right to decide to not execute some parts of laws.

Comment: @Acccumulation, an apt analogy: Law: It is illegal to punch a cop in the face. Executive order: punching a cop in the face is allowed if the perpetrator is wearing a yellow hat and the president will determine what yellow is according to how cute/young the perp is.

Comment: I'm OK with the edit in general, as I'm not showing the paragraphs in the lawsuit where those terms were defined. But I added a note to the beginning to indicate that the quoted portion was modified.